# jspdf Some data is being cut

Tags: vue.js, jspdf

The jspdf library is being used to generate PDF files in html.
That's a really good thing.
But I have a problem with pdf.
The data is about three pages long, but if check the downloaded pdf file, I see only one page and the rest will be truncated.

Here's my code:

```
let pdfName = this.contractlist_detail.title
var doc = new jsPDF();
var NotoSansCJKjp;

doc.addFileToVFS('NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.ttf', VFS);
doc.addFont('NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.ttf', 'NotoSansCJKjp', 'Bold');
doc.setFont('NotoSansCJKjp', 'Bold');
doc.setFontSize(12);

var paragraph = data;
var lines = doc.splitTextToSize(paragraph, 150);
doc.text(15, 15, lines)
doc.save(pdfName + '.pdf');
```

How do I make all of my data visible to downloaded pdf without being truncated?

Answer (score 0):

jspdf library doesn't handle multi-pages by its own. You need to add pages manually when content is cropped (you need also to calculate manually if text is cropped).

Here is the method to add a new page :
[addPage method](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#addPage)

a demo is available in section "two page hello world" to know how to use this method
[enter link description here](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/)